# Retrieving User Details using SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I want to retrieve details of the users of our Marketing Cloud account using SOAP. Looked through the document and created the below SOAP envelop. It is working fine but does not retrieve the Associated Business Units and Roles for the users

What am I missing?

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<s:Header>
  <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Retrieve</a:Action>
  <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:5dfca442-f1a0-4f7c-9419-8ace5658d2a3</a:MessageID>
  <a:ReplyTo>
     <a:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</a:Address>
  </a:ReplyTo>
  <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://webservice.s6.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx</a:To>
  <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
     <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-88b91f91-bac2-489b-90fb-37e7b256e20c-1">
        <o:Username>xxx</o:Username>
        <o:Password>xxx</o:Password>
     </o:UsernameToken>
  </o:Security>
</s:Header>
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
  <RetrieveRequest>

     <ObjectType>AccountUser</ObjectType>
     <QueryAllAccounts>true</QueryAllAccounts> // to enable child accounts
     <Properties>email</Properties>
     <Properties>ActiveFlag</Properties>
     <Properties>CreatedDate</Properties>
     <Properties>isAPIUser</Properties>
     <Properties>UserID</Properties>
     <Properties>LastSuccessfulLogin</Properties>
      <AssociatedBusinessUnits>
        <BusinessUnit>
     <Properties>Name</Properties>
     </BusinessUnit>
     </AssociatedBusinessUnits>
     <Roles>
        <Role>
     <Properties>Name</Properties>
     </Role>
     </Roles>

  </RetrieveRequest>
  </RetrieveRequestMsg>
</s:Body>
 </s:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do another retrieve on the BusinessUnit object after you've retrieved AccountUser.  I don't think the Roles are retrievable.

Here's a sample SOAP envelope from a live API call:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Retrieve</a:Action>
      <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:d8aeb570-eb26-4ed3-9cf0-613df4de08b7</a:MessageID>
      <a:ReplyTo>
         <a:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</a:Address>
      </a:ReplyTo>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <ClientIDs>
               <ClientID>MID_GOES_HERE</ClientID>
               <ID>MID_GOES_HERE</ID>
            </ClientIDs>
            <ObjectType>AccountUser</ObjectType>
            <Properties>ID</Properties>
            <Properties>CreatedDate</Properties>
            <Properties>ModifiedDate</Properties>
            <Properties>Client.ID</Properties>
            <Properties>AccountUserID</Properties>
            <Properties>UserID</Properties>
            <Properties>Name</Properties>
            <Properties>Email</Properties>
            <Properties>MustChangePassword</Properties>
            <Properties>ActiveFlag</Properties>
            <Properties>ChallengePhrase</Properties>
            <Properties>ChallengeAnswer</Properties>
            <Properties>IsAPIUser</Properties>
            <Properties>NotificationEmailAddress</Properties>
            <Properties>Client.PartnerClientKey</Properties>
            <Properties>Password</Properties>
            <Properties>Locale.LocaleCode</Properties>
            <Properties>TimeZone.ID</Properties>
            <Properties>TimeZone.Name</Properties>
            <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
            <Properties>DefaultBusinessUnit</Properties>
            <Properties>LanguageLocale.LocaleCode</Properties>
            <Properties>Client.ModifiedBy</Properties>
            <QueryAllAccounts>true</QueryAllAccounts>
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: How will I pass the user information to the second retrieve call ?

Comment: Hi @Adam Spriggs 
Could Please give suggestion for getting marketing cloud  userinstace through soap api
for Ex: S7,    S6 Like